# A characterisation of the convex hull that is not obvious.

Tags: complex-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-hulls

It says that if `x` is not in the convex hull of a compact  `K`, then there exists an affine map `f` for which the norm of `f(x)` is greater than its supremum in `K`. Does anyone have a proof for this.

Comment: Is there any context? If $0 \not\in K$, then $x=0$ seems to be a counterexample

Comment: @LinAlg The correct claim involves affine, not linear, maps.

Comment: By a linear map you probably mean an affine function.

Comment: @LinAlg yes you're right, but as DonThousand said, the map is actually affine. My bad I thought only french uses the term affine.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Yes you're right.

Comment: I'd imagine you can use this in your proof: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supporting_hyperplane#Supporting_hyperplane_theorem

Comment: See [hyperplane separation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane_separation_theorem) or, more generally, Hahn-Banach theorem.

Comment: @user436658 yes that's where I started but it doesn't seem to go anywhere, maybe am doing something wrong.